# how to add relationship within joined records in NEO4J

Tags: database, neo4j

i have two records ('orders' and 'menulist') that are joined with 'orderitem' by orderID nad menuID
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kF8R.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sabUE.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sqk1.png

i was trying to promote each orderitem record into a relationship in the graph
what I did is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Orders)
SET n = row

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///menulist.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Menu)
SET n = row

CREATE INDEX FOR (m:Menu) ON (m.MenuID)
CREATE INDEX FOR (o:Orders) ON (o.OrderID)

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orderitem.csv" AS row
MATCH  (m:Menu), (o:Orders)
WHERE m.MenuID = row.MenuID AND o.orderID = row.orderID
CREATE (o)-[oi:CONTAINS]->(m)
SET oi = row,
oi.Quantity = toInteger(row.Quantity)
```

but I got (no changes, no records), seems there is an error here, can anyone help to solve?

Comment: solved! 
i changed "o.orderID = row.orderID" to "o.OrderID = row.OrderID"

Answer (score 0):

That is not the proper way of creating node from csv. Follow the examples found in this link: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file

In your example, remove the Set n = row because it will not assign the columns in the csv to each property in the node. You need to define the attributes one at a time. See below.

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row
 CREATE (  :Orders {ID: row.OrderID, <and so on> , paymentID: row.PaymentID  })
```

Also notice that the variable n in label :Orders is not needed.

Comment: i think my way of creating node works for others relationship than the joined one
for example for adding 'Orders'
i tried:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Orders)
SET n = row

it works for this node and it's relationships

Comment: I agree with Jose that this is probably not the best way to create nodes from CSVs but it will work as when WITH HEADERS is used each row is returned as a map and  setting a node's properties from a map is supported.
It definitely won't work if WITH HEADERS is absent as each row returned is a list of values and therefore has no way to know which properties to set in the node.